# GothamBold font not rendering on Safari

Tags: fonts, safari

I use GothamBook and GothamBold on my website. GothamBook is rendered correctly but no GothamBold, only on Safari.

I don't know why the bold is not redering...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham HTF';
    src: url("font/GothamHTF-Book.woff") format("woff");
    url("font/GothamBook.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham HTF';
    src: url("font/Gotham-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
    url("font/Gotham-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("font/Gotham-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Working : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/05/5/1549031420-51034508-622499171534647-4506454994643320832-n.png

Not working : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/05/5/1549031420-51176106-755763351461937-4132132935346159616-n.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Old safari version doesn't support this type of declaration. I need to declare font with different name :

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Gotham HTF';
 src: url("font/GothamHTF-Book.woff") format("woff");
 url("font/GothamBook.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Gotham HTF Bold';
 src: url("font/Gotham-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
 url("font/Gotham-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"),
 url("font/Gotham-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```